# CSS to change visibility or display not working in IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

I have these two similar buttons, I want one of them to work on IE (11+) and other on Chrome

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btnKabulFisiExplorer" class="btn btn-primary float-right" style="margin-right: 10px; visibility:hidden"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></i> Kabul Fişi Explorer</a>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btnKabulFisi" class="btn btn-primary float-right" style="margin-right: 10px;"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></i> Kabul Fişi</a>
```

One of them, the explorer one have `visibility:hidden` inside style.

I'm using this css to change the visibilities between browsers (aiming only ie 11 )

```
@@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
            #btnKabulFisiExplorer{
                visibility:visible;
            }
            #btnKabulFisi{
                display:none;
            }
        }
```

But it is not working to make the button visible. I also tried to change display attribute too but didn't work. It works very well on changing other buttons `display` attribute though.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why @@ media screen?

Comment: this page https://paper-leaf.com/blog/2014/09/targeting-ie-10-11-browsers-css/ and using only @model is giving a media not found error. Since it works on other buttons, I assumed @@ part is not the problem

Comment: @EgeBayrak That page has only one @...

Comment: I know, I found @@usage in same page I'm working on. Using only @model gave a "the name media is not found in current context" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because inline CSS has higher priority than outer CSS. Since you don't have inline `display` CSS set, so that's why it's working while `visibility: hidden;` is set inline.

Simply move your inline CSS to class rule of CSS file or tag.

Also check if it's not error with `@@` before `media` (`@@media ...`)

Comment: Correct, but for me the problem was somewhere else. It seem that when I used visibility: unset it wasn't working on IE11. I just changed to visibility: visible and it worked.